# Cannot set app icon with transparency to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

iTunes Connect has been updated in the last few days, now when I try to update App Icon (not screenshot) I get the following error:"Images can't contain alpha channels or transparencies."

[image]

I had no such trouble in the past, has Apple changed its guideline on app icon or is this perhaps a bug in the new site? If the guideline has been changed, is the solution to simply remove any transparency?

Comment: Its mistake in your app icon that contain some alpha and transparencies , need to change it, yesterday I also uploaded one application then getting same error, after change app icon by designer, It has uploaded successfully.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681869/images-cant-contain-alpha-channels-or-transparencies

Comment: **A Simple Hack!!!**

Convert You png to jpg format and good to go. [Convert Now][1]


  [1]: https://png2jpg.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your icon should be without transparency(Alpha Channel) and of size 1024 X 1024. It could be either JPEG, JPG or PNG type. [Refer apple doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)

I have also attached a screenshot for which highlights the size & other specs for icon.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, has it always being the case that no transparency/alpha is allowed?

Comment: no they have changed it a while ago. but no onwards they don't allow alpha.

Comment: OK this clears things up as I distinctively remember that it was allowed

Comment: **A Simple Hack!!!**

Convert You png to jpg format and good to go. [Convert Now][1]


  [1]: https://png2jpg.com/

Answer (score 45):

Here is the cool stuff which will solve this problem.

Step 1 - Open your icon image in Preview
Step 2 - Go to File -> Export, You will get a drop-down as shown in the image below.
Step 3 - Uncheck the Alpha and Save

Then use the exported icon Image. Now it will work.

[image: Exporting icon image]

Comment: Great stuff.... I changed my image from png to jpg but that did not remove alpha channels.. This solution worked form me.... Thanks

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction but didn't quite work for my file.  For me, what happened was Preview saved a blank image when I did File -> Export and unchecked Alpha.  What did work however was to Save As a new file name and uncheck Alpha on the Save As dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

Remove any transparency from your app icon and try to upload app icon after that... [See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html)

Answer (score 1):

- Open your image(1024x1024) with Gimp and go to File --> Export
- Select File Type as JPEG image and click Export button on the right bottom corner.

[image]