# use same app icon as previous version

Tags: ios

In iTunes connect website, I went to upload a new version of my iOS app and I noticed there is an empty placeholder for the app icon.

I would assume that it doesn't make sense for developers to have to upload a new app icon with every version.

How can we just use the old app icon?

[image]

Comment: are you uploaded the new verson or curent verson + 1

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I went from version 1.6 to version 1.7.1

Comment: check once unfortunately created the new verson, if you created the existing verson, it defaultly comes bro,

Comment: If you are uploading an update to an app existing in the app store, it will definitely come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Apple now forces app icons to not have transparencies.

My icon contained Alphas.

I had to remove alpha by doing a File->Export from Mac Preview by unchecking alpha and uploading the exported .png to iTunes Connect.

The transparency could be the reason why the icon was removed, because I have used this icon during many updates before, but Apple no longer allows icons with transparency.

As stated in this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758384/cannot-set-app-icon-with-transparency-to-itunes-connect) post.