# Removing the Alpha channel from an image in Preview 9

Tags: macos, alpha

Preview has had the capability to remove the alpha channel from an image.  See [Remove alpha channel in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171739/remove-alpha-channel-in-an-image)

Preview 9 (OS 10.12.4) does not appear to have the alpha channel toggle box.  Can someone recommend a method for deleting the alpha channel from an image in Preview 9?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting to jpg should lose the alpha channel even though there isn't any toggle box, but doing so results in a small amount of quality loss.

To avoid that you can use free image editing applications as [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/).