# Missing Marketing Icon

Tags: ios, xcode

When trying to submit my app, iTunes Connect says

> Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the Marketing Icon cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review.

I do have a 1024x1024px PNG in my submission in iTunes Connect, under `General App Information` and `App Icon`. So I guess they want me to add it as an Asset to the bundle, in Xcode. But when I drag and drop my PNG to this `Unassigned` placeholder, nothing happens.

[image: Unassigned placeholder for Marketing 1024x PNG]

This error started appearing after WWDC 2017 and I installed XCode 9 Beta. This issue is occuring in Version 8.3.1 (8E1000a) too though.

Comment: Did you tried to drag & drop 1024x1024px PNG icon?

Comment: May be it will help you https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#appstore

Comment: No, it doesn't your bundle. Ensure that the icon yo have uploaded to iTunesConnect doesn't contain an alpha channel

Comment: @Paulw11I removed the alpha like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38256612/237509 and reuploaded but upon submitting I still get the same message.

Comment: @DSDharma yes I tried drag&drop both to "Unassigned" in Xcode but it does not react on drag&drop, and to iTunes Connect in the app submission, to reupload the icon there, but no success.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Solved by adding iOS Marketing 1024pt icon in project
[image]

Comment: In my case it was named "App Store iOS" as opposed to "iOS Marketing", but still the icon is in the very end of the list, and the only one with that size, so there shouldn't be any confusion.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Same issue happens with Xcode 9 official release. It's not a bug, Apple just requires 1 more icon format for the newly designed App Store.

Comment: FYI. If you also develop for Android you'll already have this size so you won't need to create it.

Comment: How can I add iOS Marketing icon to the list in appIcon? I dont have it listed but app store still requires it. :/

Comment: This helps me. But I think it would be correct if validation would tell about the missing info which it didn't in my case.

Comment: I have xcode 9 and added the App Store Ios icon which then allowed me to upload the build. HOWEVER itunesconnect now rejects the submission to the App Store due to Missing Marketing Icon.

Answer (score 78):

**According to new guidelines for the XCode 9**: we need to drag a new icon with size 1024pt new available icon item named "App Store iOS 1024pt" under AppIcon image set.

[image]

**IMPORTANT: Make sure to use the icon without Alpha/Transparency**

After doing this, the warning will be gone and you should be able to successfully submit the binary to Apple for review.

**Reference link: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev4b0ebb1bb**

Comment: I still have the warning though!

Comment: Who told Apple that dragging should be the only option to perform an operation? I was staring at the context menu for 30mins, until I read this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

The issue seems to be submitting a binary that was built using a beta version of Xcode. Use a released version of Xcode when submitting builds to the App Store.

Comment: Marking as Answer. So the issue was connected to the bundle, and this particular bundle I had was archived by Xcode 9 Beta. Silly me, but still Apple should have made the message clear if it was the bundle or the separate submission contents on iTunes Connect.

Comment: Adding a marketing icon is mandatory and this answer provides just a temporary workaround.

Comment: I now have the XCode 9 GM seed (non-beta) and I get this issue.

Comment: @Crag in XCode 9 GM, inside AppIcon at Assets, you will find the icon in the end. It was called "App Store" in my case, and not "iOS Marketing" as in the screenshot in the answer by Varinder.

Comment: @TGO I have a Contents.json file in that folder with "idiom": "ios-marketing", but the filename isn't set... I'm building through Cordova, so I'd rather not set that manually as I'll blow it away...

Comment: @Crag sorry if I wasn't clear. [Screenshot to what I meant](https://imgur.com/SNBrdqx). Blurred irrelevant parts. But yes, you can also edit the json, `{
      "size" : "1024x1024",
      "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
      "filename" : "logo_filename.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    }`

Comment: This should be unmarked: it is incorrect. Builds from beta Xcodes are unacceptable in the first place, icon or no icon. TGO's answer is correct.

Answer (score 15):

For people that still facing problems after adding the new app icon:

Make sure the 'Transparency' checkbox is unchecked when you're exporting the PNG image from Photoshop. Apparently this is an issue even if the image has no transparency.

[image: Uncheck the transparency checkbox in Photoshop]

This worked for me.

Thanks to Hammoud's answer at [How to solve "Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667434/how-to-solve-missing-marketing-icon-ios-apps-must-include-a-1024x1024px)

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me finally too. Would never have guessed that (:

Answer (score 15):

In Xcode 8:
Find your iconset directory, put a prepared file (for example 'Icon-Marketing.png') here and add the following to Contents.json

```
{
  "size" : "1024x1024",
  "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
  "filename" : "Icon-Marketing.png",
  "scale" : "1x"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are building an IOS app from Unity follow [these steps](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/xcode-9-ios-warning-missing-marketing-icon-is-thrown-when-uploading-an-app-to-itunes-connect):

1. In the Xcode project go to Unity-iPhone > Images.xcassets > AppIcon
2. Scroll to the bottom
3. Drag in a 1024x1024 icon
4. Build (CMD+B), archive, upload as usual

Answer (score 6):

The App Icon guidelines have changed with the release of new iPhons X, iOS 11, and Xcode 9.

A new App Store icon should be added to the project in Xcode 9 of size:

1024px × 1024px (1024pt × 1024pt @1x)

Hope this helps.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/

Note: As of today, [Technical Q&A QA1686 - App Icons on iPhone, iPad and Apple Watch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html) hasn't been updated with this requirement.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using beta 3 and I'm only getting a warning after uploading. I uploaded a binary for Test Flight, not release.

Adding the marketing image in .xcassets , AppIcon fixed the warning.

Answer (score 3):

How to add "1024 application icon" in sys cordova?

edit config file:

```
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" height="1024" />
```

command line:

```
cordova prepare ios
```

Don't forget to actually add the file `res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png` to the filesystem.

Comment: Hi user3585515! Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can add this as a separate question of it's on, and answer it yourself, if you like.

Comment: thank you. i send now question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875315/cordova-phonegap-and-ionic-ios-missing-1024x1024-icon/46875316#46875316

Answer (score 0):

I was submitting an update of the iOS app to the Apple app store.
I found the below error : 
`Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the Marketing Icon cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review`

According to new Apple guide line in xcode 9, we need to add support of "App Store iOS" icon
So I added to App icon of 1024x1024pt.
App is submitted to App Store.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be in the other icons. I created the 1024 icon without alpha-channel but this didn't help. Then, I removed all icons and upload it again. This helped.