# How to solve "Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px"

Tags: ios, xcode

I am uploading app in iTunes from Xcode 9.0...This error is showing on the last step. How to solve this? 1024x1024px icon is present in my icons list

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it really 1024x1024? You should check it again..

Comment: Check in iTunes, there is one field to upload your 1024X1024 size app icon and than try to submit again.

Comment: Yes , i have shared second screen shot of my icon details. @ ridvankucuk

Comment: Did the AppIcon update on apps page in iTunesConnect?

Comment: started bountry for this same qus in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565883/missing-marketing-icon

Comment: Note that once this happens, you have to change the build number of the next version you upload. Frigging Apple. You can't do anything with the version that doesn't have the marketing icon but you can't even get the crap removed.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Now onwards we need to add a new icon in our project with the size 1024X1024. Please see below-attached image. This issue was stared from WWDC 2017.

[image]

Note: - Do not upload or use the beta version (mac os or Xcode) for app upload. As per Apple recommendation. I already got mail from Apple about this.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me. Here is the relevant documentation. Previously this was uploaded via iTunes Connect. In Xcode 9, it should be in Xcode.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev4b0ebb1bb

Answer (score 37):

**For the XCode 9**: we need to drag a new icon with size 1024pt new available icon item named "App Store iOS 1024pt" under AppIcon image set.

[image]

**Make sure to use icon in PNG format without alpha/transparency.** Thanks to [@Hammoud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2480150/hammoud) for sharing transparency experience !

After doing this stuff, this warning should be gone and you should be able to see something like this.
[image]

Happy Coding !

Comment: Ran into this exact issue after updating to Xcode 9, this fixed it for me. Note- this issue isn't caught if you validate your archive, so check for this icon manually after updating.

Comment: What does you Contents.json look like after adding the icon. Mine says:
{
      "size" : "1024x1024",
      "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
      "filename" : "App Store iOS 1024pt.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    }
But it still gives me the same error. :(

Answer (score 11):

I was stuck at this problem for about 2 hours. I had a icon present in my icon list but it keeps on failing. The problem was that the PNG had alpha channel enabled. Open up photoshop and save your image without alhpa/transparency.

Solution found at:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86829

Answer (score 7):

Tap little grey circle arrow next to App Icons Source to go to the icon drag/drop screen.

[image: Tap little arrow next to App Icon to go to the icon drag/drop screen. Then go to the bottom and drag your new 1024 icon in the 1024 slot]

[image]

Then go to the bottom and drag your new 1024 icon in the 1024 slot

Hint: Your iTunesArtwork@2x.png icon is the same thing as this requirement and you already have it because you already use it in the App Store through iTunes Connect

Comment: It's correct, here is apple's intruction:
Icon size: 1024px × 1024px (1024pt × 1024pt @1x). 
Layers: Flattened with no transparency.
Format: PNG.
Shape: Square with no rounded corners

Comment: PS: I got an error when using png icon, so i changed it to jpg and everything worked fine.

I have written a step by step guide on how to solve the missing icon issue here. Hope it helps some one. Thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987694/missing-app-store-icon-ios-apps-must-include-a-1024x1024px-app-store-icon-in/47131552#answer-47131552

Answer (score 3):

Since XCode 12 you will have to explicitly activate "Mac" in your Assets as a Device for macCatalyst apps:

[image: Asses]

After you have done that, you will see some new frames inside the main windows where you can add AppIcons for Mac.

You have to add your 1024x1024 logo to the new frame "Mac 512pt 1024x1024px".
The other Mac-AppIcons can be left empty.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem, there is my check steps:

1. i check all the image of AppIcon ,the other images are ok, but there is a error:

> ERROR ITMS-90704: "Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog of apps built for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, apps cannot be submitted for review. For details, see https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/."

2. i check the pixel alpha and transparent, those is all ok ,but the same is all the same :(
3. i create a new asset catalog, and move the AppIcon dir to the new dir:Media.Xcassets. it works!

if u have tried all the above method and have nothing effective, u can try mine, have a good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, follow @Sukeshj 's solution.

If @Sukeshj 's solution doesn't work and you are using CocoaPods for project management, that may be the key point.

My environment: XCode 9.1 CocoaPods 1.2.1

Find {porject}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-{porjectname}/Pods-{porjectname}-resources.sh in Xcode, and change the last piece of code like this:

before change:

```
printf "%s\0" "${XCASSET_FILES[@]}" | xargs -0 xcrun actool --output-
format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --platform 
"${PLATFORM_NAME}" --minimum-deployment-target 
"${!DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME}" ${TARGET_DEVICE_ARGS} --
compress-pngs --compile 
"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"

fi
```

after change:

```
printf "%s\0" "${XCASSET_FILES[@]}" | xargs -0 xcrun actool --output-
format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --platform 
"${PLATFORM_NAME}" --minimum-deployment-target 
"${!DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME}" ${TARGET_DEVICE_ARGS} --
compress-pngs --compile 
"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-
icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-
plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"

fi
```

Try to archive your project and upload it again, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **`Cordova`** Framework then:

- Create an icon file with `height=1024px` and `width=1024px`. You can name the file as `icon-1024.png`
- Put that icon in folder `res/icon/ios/`
- Write the following code in your `config.xml` file.

  ```
  <platform name="ios">
      <icon height="1024" src="res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
  </platform>
  ```
- Open terminal/command-prompt, then `cd` to your project's root directory and run the following command:

  ```
  cordova prepare ios --verbose
  ```
- This will copy the `icon-1024.png` file to its proper location (`platforms/ios/YourProjectName/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/`)

Answer (score -1):

Its mandatory to add app icon of size 1024*1024 in image asset for Xcode 9 or later. Other wise it will give following error after uploading build to app store. So please make sure to add app icon in image asset before uploading app.

Dear developer, We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "CarPal". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery: Missing Marketing Icon - iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the Marketing Icon cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review. After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.