# Missing Marketing Icon iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, icons, app-store, app-store-connect, appcelerator

I have uploaded a couple of applications to the app store with ease. Sometimes I noticed this warning in xCode when I uploaded my app:

> Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the Marketing Icon cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review.

But that was not impeding me to send my app for review in iTunes connect... until now.

I have found a few questions about this but none of those have helped me solving my problem. For example, following advise given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565883/missing-marketing-icon) I tried adding my icon width xCode in the AppIcon.iconset file but it doesn't work if I do it **after** packaging my app with appcelerator (I guess that is the normal outcome). But if I do it and the package again, the icon disappears from the file (I think this is because appcelerator generates those files on its own).

How do I add that icon so appcelerator won't remove it when I package?
Or how do I add it to appcelerator so it generates the iconset including my marketing Icon??

I believe I have followed the guidelines completely (My icon is a .png file, its size is 1024x1024 and has no alpha channels nor transparencies) maybe the naming is not correct but I have not found any specific naming for this case.

Answer (score 3):

Use the latest SDK (6.2.2.GA). It was fixed in 6.2.1.GA (https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/9451).

If you can't use it you could add the changes in the PR to your _build.js file

Comment: Thank goodness this worked! I've been struggling with this one and couldn't progress with my tasks. Thanks a lot mate.