# Cordova, Phonegap and ionic ( ios missing 1024x1024 icon )

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

> Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing
>   Icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the Marketing Icon cannot
>   be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review.

when you **upload your application to the apple store** magazine, you get a similar error with the above article?

You can find and apply the solution below.

Now the apple store wants to have **1024x1024px** icon in the application. Otherwise, it will not allow the approval process.

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to add "1024 application icon" in sys cordova?

edit config file:

```
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" height="1024" />
```

command line:

```
cordova prepare ios
```

Don't forget to actually add the file `res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png` to the filesystem.

Comment: Do you add the `<icon` tag to the Cordova **config.xml** file, within `<platform name="ios">`? Also, where is the **res/icon/ios** directory within a cordova project?

Comment: yes <icon> edit file config.xml you any other directory. Simple
<icon src="yourfolder" width="1024" height="1024" />

Comment: i added as you say and the build still was rejected due to this error.