# Phonegap - Missing App Store Icon 1024x1024px App Store Icon

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, testflight, phonegap, application-loader

This is for PhoneGap.

When submitting the .ipa with ApplicationLoader I'm getting this error:

> WARNING ITMS-90704: "Missing App Store Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store Icon in PNG format. Without providing the icon in the Asset Catalog or via iTunes Connect, apps cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/ for more information."

I use Phonegap's online build tool at https://build.phonegap.com to generate the .ipa.
So, I zip the phonegap project and then upload. The website will compile and create the .ipa. The ipa gets gerenated successfully and I can even install to a test device and it also gets to the TestFlight, but Apple does not allow me to submit to app store until this warning is resolved.

I looked at other solutions but those seem to be for Cordova specifically.

I tried thse suggestions from the following links but those didn't work.

[Missing Marketing Icon - iOS Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309992/missing-marketing-icon-ios-cordova)

[Cordova, Phonegap and ionic ( ios missing 1024x1024 icon )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875315/cordova-phonegap-and-ionic-ios-missing-1024x1024-icon)

I tried updating the config.xml by adding:

```
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" height="1024" />
```

I also added the following to config.xml:

```
<platfrom name="ios">
   <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="1024" />
   ...
</platform>
```

I also added the following for the heck of it:

```
<engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.1" />
```

Nothing seems to work. Again, this is for PhoneGap. 
Thanks

Comment: You mean Phonegap build or Phonegap CLI?

Comment: Neither. I've been using their online build https://build.phonegap.com/
So, I zip up everything and upload. The website will compile and create and IPA. Everything works except I get this Warning. I can even test it in TestFlight, but Apple does not allow me to submit to app store until this warning is resolved.

Comment: That’s phonegap build. They have just updated the servers to use Xcode 9, do you set any cli version to use? Try setting it to 7.1.0

Comment: Is there any more info on this? I tired phonegap build, adding preference phonegap-version cli-7.1.0 but now I get other errors regarding some of the other icons. If I remove the line referencing the icon causing the error it tells me another icon is missing. If I remove all the icons references then tells me the ICON google-services.json is missing :S

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your `config.xml` file, add the corresponding 1024x1024 icon in png format

```
<icon src="icon/ios/icon.png" width="1024" height="1024" />
```

and update to phonegap-cli 7.1.0 or later (add this element if you don't already specify the phonegap version)

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />
```

NOTE: make sure your png icon does not contain an alpha channel (no transparency allowed, else you'll get an `ERROR ITMS-90717`).

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks a lot!!! 
Also, to add, if you have plugins and if you are giving it specific version, e.g. spec="1.2.1", you want to remove the spec versions as those might be too old and won't wotk with cli-7.

Comment: Saved me a LOT of frustration!! Thanks catu! 

Note: at first cli-7.1.0 wouldn't compile, but did AFTER I removed all the spec="X.X.X" settings in my config.xml file - some of them were too old for cli-7.1.0 to work

Comment: Specify the icon where? In the config.xml file?

Comment: this path (icon/ios/icon.png) is standard or custom? In other words, have I to edit it for my case or not?

Comment: I have already that line but I have anyway the error... is the path standard? where have I to put my icon and with which name?

Comment: I think png name is not the problem.Like <icon height="1024" src="res/icon/ios/ItunesArtwork@2x.png" width="1024" /> that I used.

Comment: This solution creates further problems whereby errors tell me that various icon files are missing. This only happens when I change the preference version to 7.1.0

Comment: I did exactly as mentioned in solution and it worked. You can put the icon in that exact path i.e. in www folder, create icon folder, create ios subfolder inside icon folder and place image there with name icon.png. Placing icon elsewhere also might work but I didn't try. Important part is to put that `<preference name...>` tag with the version your project is built.

Answer (score 2):

For others that above solution not work.

- What work for me is by uploading the 1024*1024 icon in iTunes Connect App Store Icon.
- Then I resubmit my ipa build again.

[iTunes Connect - App Store Icon Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vHrx.png)

Comment: I uploaded a logo by App Connect (as ITunes Connect no longer exists). But that didn't fix it for me :(

Comment: same as @James , once I attach the build, that icon changed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xcode to make IPA. Then open project/platforms/iOS/.../images.xcassets folder and put an app icon there named "icon-1024.png". It should be 1024*1024 px in size. Not need to be add in config.xml. Done.

Note- whether you are using xcode or not there should be images.xcassets folder. Just find it..

Comment: I've been using their online build too at https://build.phonegap.com/
So, I zip up everything and upload. The website will compile and create the .ipa. Everything works except I get this Warning. I can even test it in TestFlight, but Apple does not allow me to submit to app store until this warning is resolved. Thx
I've never tried using Xcode to compile a Phonegap project. Not sure if it's possible.

Comment: I didn't use the phone gap online build tool and don't  have much idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

You may need add assets.car file witch is required by ios 11
and you can create it with xcode or online tool http://www.applicationloader.net/appuploader/icontool.php