# Cordova specifying phonegap version above cli-6.5.0 breaks cordova-plugin-statusbar on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm currently working on a cordova app with phonegap build for iOS and I am running into an issue with submitting my app. I had everything working properly with the statusbar and had the following preferences in my config.xml:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#450084" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

This has worked before and has been working in past builds. When I went to submit my app in application loader I got the following error:

> WARNING ITMS-90704: "Missing App Store Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store Icon in PNG format. Without providing the icon in the Asset Catalog or via iTunes Connect, apps cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/ for more information."

Which lead me to the following question: [Phonegap - Missing App Store Icon 1024x1024px App Store Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236079/phonegap-missing-app-store-icon-1024x1024px-app-store-icon)

I had the icon defined already in my directories and it was for sure there, so I implemented the most popular answer on that question and added the following line to my code. I can submit successfully now:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />
```

But now when I go to run my app, I can't edit any aspect of the status bar and It just shows up as transparent. I know the preferences work because they work when I don't specify a version and it is defaulted to an earlier version of phonegap (https://build.phonegap.com/current-support) but when I set it to 7.1.0 in order to fix the icon submit error the statusbar plugin stops working.

How can I either submit an app that is phonegap version 6.5.0 that passes the 1024x1024 icon missing error, or how do I get the statusbar plugin to function correctly on a phonegap version 7.1.0 or higher?

Thanks for the help.