# Not able to upload IPA after applying App thinning

Tags: ios, ipa, app-thinning

I have applied App Thinning while creating IPA file in order to recuse the app size. The IPA files for iPhone, iPad are created successfully. If I try to upload the app with Transporter app, Im getting the following error.

Asset validation failed (90704) Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog of apps built for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, apps cannot be submitted for review. For details, see https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/. (ID: 39b914bd-2d61-4bfb-a021-fd6f542867c8)
Asset validation failed (90190) Invalid Info.plist Key. The key 'UISupportedDevices' in the Info.plist file is not valid. (ID: 4094654a-c9a0-4260-b46b-7fa61d062c16)

I have my 1024*1024 images available in assets catalog.
In my entire app there is no keyword "UISupportedDevices".
Not sure what exactly is the issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue in the past and I think what you are seeing may be due to an xcode issue with images having an alpha channel.

Try to remove alpha channel ([see this answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38256612/4944020)) from your 1024x1024 app icon asset. Replace your asset with this new image.

See if you're able to get your build through. If not, share the outcome here and we'll see where we get to.

Comment: I have tried this too, Removing alpha from all the images in AppIcon section. But nothing worked and getting the same issue. I'm currently using Xcode 14.1.