# I am trying to publish my flutter application to App Store but I got an invalid App Store Icon error

Tags: flutter, dart, app-store

I am publishing my application through Xcode for the first time but I got the error below.

[image]

### Error Message below

Invalid App Store Icon. The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in 'Runner.app' can't be transparent not contain an alpha channel. (ID 92c246d0-1226-4b59-ba5d-791e719c0000)

### What I have done

I have double check my Asset folder and App Icon but I don't figure what it wrong with my App Icon. I don't know how to troubleshoot this error, I have check online for a suitable solution but I got nothing. I will appreciate a quick solution because I am indeed stuck .

[image]

Comment: What image format is your app icon? Does it contain transparent pixels? Judging from the screenshot, I'd say they probably do.

Comment: The image format is in png @Abion47

Comment: The error message makes it clear that the image cannot contain transparency of any kind. You will need to edit your image to have an opaque background.

Comment: What do you mean by transparent pixel. How do I know if it contain transparent pixel. Please guide me. I am new to this. @Abion47

Comment: I don't know how to explain that. Transparent pixel means a pixel that is transparent. The alpha channel has a value that is less than the maximum. If you were to overlay the image over another image, you would see the second image under the first. See more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(graphic)

Comment: try to follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38256612/4899849. So at the beginning remove alpha channel from your image, save it and then create all iOS assets using online generator like: https://makeappicon.com

Comment: @Abion47 I understand what you are talking about, Opaque is definitely the opposite of transparency. I will work my image.

Comment: @Volodymyr thank you for solution as well. I will put all of your solution in to use and revert back on this channel.

Comment: If you put it on a red background, do you have a black square containing your logo on a red surrounding, or do you have red color right up next to the green?

Comment: @Volodymyr the solution you refer me to did not work for me is still error. I edited the image by unchecking the Alpha attribute then save the image, when I view my image the background change to white. Then after I make use of makeappicon.com  to generete new icon. but still I got the same error.

Comment: can anyone else can help me with another solution, I will really appreciate

Answer (score 4):

add this in config flutter_launcher_icons
`remove_alpha_ios: true`

Comment: for more info: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/253