# Can't upload screenshots to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, image, upload, app-store-connect

I want to upload an update for my app. The build is already approved and I want to upload screenshots for all the devices. Now the problem is that when I want to upload the screenshots iTunes Connect it says

> Screenshots may not contain transparencies or alpha channels.

Same goes for my large icon I wanted to add to a new app I created. There were DEFINITELY no alpha channels or transparencies in any image I tried to upload.

So does anyone know how to fix this?

(I thought iTunes Connect had an error so I waited a day but that did not help...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images can't contain alpha channels or transparencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681869/images-cant-contain-alpha-channels-or-transparencies)

Comment: convert to .png and Check this link: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the images to JPG, generally PNG images have an alpha channel set.

Alternatively, you can re-export the images  using Preview on Mac and uncheck the "Alpha" checkbox.

Comment: @LiGe  That's odd, what tool are you using to convert the images? Try this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681869/images-cant-contain-alpha-channels-or-transparencies

Comment: Brilliant! Always glad when it works out in the end:) have a great day

Comment: For the new Itunes, the new uploader says to upgrade your OS and Safari in order to upload video previews. Recently this seems to be true for screenshots as well. The drag and drop works fine on Chrome, though.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson probably because you update Chrome regularly and not Safari?

Comment: I update both browsers regularly - but since Itunes Connect said I should update OS X as well as Safari (and this would mean having to pay for a new license of a software I use heavily), I just tried it in Chrome and it worked. Sometimes you need to get an app out, Chrome allowed me to finish the app upload in a time frame acceptable to the client.

Comment: In general, web developers should provide solutions that work on browsers (browser versions) that represent as large an audience as possible.