# Apple watch alpha channel error while uploading

Tags: apple-watch

I receive an error about Alpha channel when trying to upload my app with Apple Watch. What should I do?
Why does XCode allow me to upload build in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this 
[Alpha channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681869/images-cant-contain-alpha-channels-or-transparencies)

You can also change it using Preview app on Mac

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool http://alphachannelremover.blogspot.com . Check this out.