# Error ITMS-90717: "Invalid App Store Icon"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

When I tried to submit an App to `Itunes Connect` I got the following error.

```
iTunes Store Operation Failed

Error ITMS-90717: "Invalid App Store Icon. The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in 'YourApp.app' can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel."
```

[image: Error ITMS-90717]
I made sure that I submitted a file with no transparency. So the error persisted in submission to `iTunes Connect`.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681869/images-cant-contain-alpha-channels-or-transparencies to me.

Comment: Unrelated to iOS or Swift.

Comment: @MartinR  the question is different. My is when you submitting the app through the Xcode, the question you show is uploading image direct to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Okay, so one big thing I was missing was to rearchive the file. Then upload it again and it work. Maybe some other noobie got stuck at that point, so here I am mentioning it.

Comment: Remove the Alpha Chanel on you App icons in project folder.

Answer (score 585, accepted):

The below solution worked for me

1. Click & open the App Store icon (1024*1024) in the preview app.
2. Export it by unticking the **Alpha** channel.
3. Replace the current App Store icon with the newly exported icon image.
4. Validate and upload.

**Note:** This will not work on Mac OS High Sierra, please try a lower version to export without alpha or use any one of the image editing applications or try out the below alternatives.

**Alternative 1: (Using Sierra or High Sierra and Ionic)**

1. Copy and Paste the App Store icon to the desktop.
2. Open the image. Click File Menu->Duplicate.
3. Save it by unticking the **Alpha** channel.
4. Replace the current App Store icon with this one.
5. Validate and upload.

**Alternative 2:** **If duplicate does not work**, try doing opening it in preview and then doing file export. I was able to unselect the alpha channel there. – [@AlejandroCorredor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4294220).

**Alternative 3 :** **Using High Sierra and Ionic,** found the problem image in the following folder: `[app name]/platforms/ios/[app name]/Images.xcassets/Appicon.appiconset/icon-1024.png`. We have to copy it to the desktop and Save As while unchecking Alpha, then rename it to `icon-1024.png`, then delete the original and copy the new file back to the original folder. Export did not work though no error was displayed and all permissions were set/777. – [@RalphHinkley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1308787)

[image]

Comment: I had to regenerate again the resources for ios, after that recompile and "archive".

Thanks

Comment: @ShamsudheenTK I am sorry to answer to an old post, but I am not able to solve this error. I did what you wrote and I am pretty sure my image does not have transparency and alpha. Do I need to to do it for all the images, or just for the App Store icon (1024x1024 size)?

Comment: @GiacomoM you should apply only to the App Store icon (1024x1024). The other assets are okay with alpha. Could you please check the Alternative option that I mentioned in my answer? Please let me know, if you are experiencing the same issue even after the Alternative option.

Comment: @ShamsudheenTK I did something like that. I did not duplicate, I opened the image and I saved it unchecking the alpha tick

Comment: @GiacomoM please try to duplicate and save it (uncheck the alpha tick). Replace the old image with the newly created one!

Comment: @ShamsudheenTK if I duplicate the file I can not check or uncheck anything. The ios just copies the file without any confirm window.

Comment: if you are getting here using Ionic 4+ it's important to note that after you remove the alpha layer and after you create the resources with `$ ionic cordova resources` you will *need* to rebuild the application with `$ ionic cordova build ios --release` for xCode to recognize the changes!

Answer (score 109):

I faced the same problem and wasn't able to fix it with the provided solution by Shamsudheen TK. Ionic somehow added transparency to my icons even if the source icon did not have any transparency at all. In the end I was able to resolve it by:

Install imagemagick (MacOS):

> brew install imagemagick

Remove alpha channel from all images in resource folder:

> find ./resources/ -name "*.png" -exec convert "{}" -alpha off "{}" \;

Comment: Thank you. I sure can't wait until the ionic/cordova team fixes the `resources` command to remove alpha channel from PNG's automatically for iOS builds.

Comment: I was also having this problem with Ionic app in MacOS High Sierra and this solution worked! Thanks!

Comment: upon running this command, is there a flag will show whats going  on  ?

Comment: Why showing me `find: convert: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Lukas showing this `find: convert: No such file or directory`, is it path problem?
I am using ionic3

Comment: Are you in the root folder of your ionic3 project? What is the output of pwd?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459080/ionic3-invalid-app-store-icon-the-app-store-icon-in-the-asset-catalog-in-you check, please

Comment: @Lukas yes, I am in root folder which I running it in VScode

Comment: @YuyangHe `convert` is part of `imagemagick`. That's why it needs to be installed.

Answer (score 44):

For anyone arriving to this question from Flutter, like myself:

1. In your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter_icons:
  android: false. // I already had android icons
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: 'assets/images/icon.png' // Your image path
```

2. Run `flutter pub get`
3. Run `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` to generate the iOS icons without alpha.

This fixed it for me after days of struggling. And yes, I did try all the solutions suggested here. Nothing else worked.

Answer (score 34):

Here is a solution that have worked for me on High Sierra

1. Open the App Store icon (1024*1024) in `Preview` app(default OSX image viewer).
2. Click on the `File` menu from the menu bar and select `Export`. 
   [view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyPje.png)
3. Uncheck `Alpha`, select where you would like to export the image and click on the `Save` button. [view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NJ4s.png)
4. Replace the current App Store icon with the newly exported icon image.
5. Validate and upload.

Answer (score 18):

If you are here and you are using Flutter, try this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Then add

```
flutter_launcher_icons:
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/logo.png"
```

to your pubspec.yaml file
It solved my own problem for me

Comment: `remove_alpha_ios: true` FTW!

Answer (score 9):

Whatever way you try above you need to test it by upload it to app connect like me to make sure it works and save your valuable time

[image]

[image]

Comment: This no longer works because App Store Connect is now extracting the icon automatically  from the uploaded app release  build

Answer (score 7):

If showing this error for **ionic3** project when you upload to iTunes Connect, please check this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459080/ionic3-invalid-app-store-icon-the-app-store-icon-in-the-asset-catalog-in-you/48495572#48495572)

This is my project error when I try to vilidated.
[image]

Finally follow this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459080/ionic3-invalid-app-store-icon-the-app-store-icon-in-the-asset-catalog-in-you/48495572#48495572), error solved.
[image]

Comment: It's specific for Ionic, since this question is not, this answer you pointed doesn't fit this question.

Answer (score 7):

*Invalid App Store Icon. The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in 'YourApp.app' can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel.*

Solved in Catalina

1. copy to desktop
2. open image in PREVIEW APP.
3. File -> Duplicate Close the first opened preview
4. after try to close the second duplicated image, then it will prompt to save there you will available to untick AlPHA

look into my screenshot

[image: nvalid App Store Icon Solved in Catalina]

Answer (score 6):

Dumb mistake from my part, didn't archive the app after removing alpha. Just kept submitting my old archived app and finding same alpha/transparency error. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

If you’re using Sierra or later

1. Navigate to `AppIcon.appiconset` folder within your Runner folder
2. Open App Icon image using preview.
3. At the topmost left of your screen select File its beside edit.
4. Within the file drop down select export.
5. Deselect alpha list item.
6. Replace the deselected alpha image with old one.

Replicate this for all App Icon images in your `Assets.xcassets`

Answer (score 5):

1. Generate App icon from here https://appicon.co/
2. Delete Assets.xcassets file (project->ios->runner)
3. Copy  Assets.xcassets from newly generated icons folder and past here (project->ios->runner)
4. perform clean build folder from XCode
5. then archive and upload new build

Answer (score 3):

An error message itself says:

> **"Invalid App Store Icon. The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in
>   'YourApp.app' can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel."**

All app icon must be square without transparency or semi transparent (`alpha value != 1.0`).

Hint: App icon may have rounded corners. (Share your app icons here)

Here is Apple guidelines for [App Icon - Human Interface](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/)

Answer (score 2):

I tried several of the things mentioned in this post (besides swapping to a .jpg) with no success.  I solved it by opening the file in photoshop and using 'export to web'.  Within that process/window is a checkbox for transparency.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the alpha channel using this command in the folder 'Images.xcassets', this command will remove all alpha channels from your .png files and it will put the background color to white

```
for i in `ls *.png`; do convert $i -background white -alpha remove -alpha off $i; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a mac, on windows you can open Paint and save as PNG with correct dimensions 1024x1024

Answer (score 1):

If you're facing this issue in Flutter then you're good to go here.

Issue is indicating you're using .png as image asset. Just try to replace .png to .jpg and build your project again..!!

Use this plugin. -   [flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

```
flutter_icons:
  android: "ic_launcher"
  image_path_android: "assets/logo_panda.jpg"
  ios: true
  image_path_ios: "assets/logo_panda.jpg"
```

Make sure you're using the .jpg image extension as the image path.

This help me to upload the app to the App Store.

Comment: The dedicated `remove_alpha_ios` flag is the recommended way, since image quality may differ for JPG files compared to PNG

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the Mac Sierra OS issue by duplicating the file, dragging the new file onto my desktop, open in preview, then click the export option (in the File menu) , then the option to save it without “alpha” comes up

Answer (score 0):

Use Alpha Channel Remover. It lets you drag icons into the app and it'll remove transparency.

Download it from here: http://alphachannelremover.blogspot.com

Update: this is not my site

Comment: Extra info: since iOS 8, Apple doesn't accept icons with transparency. You have to design a square icon, which can be a background color of choice with your icon in the center.

Comment: Is this your site? Please explicitly state if it is or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was because my app store icon wasn't explicitly listed in my `config.xml`. Once I added the line

`<icon height="1024" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />`,

cordova copied it over correctly without adding an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:(**Using Sierra or High Sierra and Ionic**)

1. Copy and Paste the App Store icon to the desktop.
2. Open the image. Click File Menu->Duplicate.
3. Save it by unticking the Alpha channel.
4. Replace the current App Store icon with this one.
5. Validate and upload.

Answer (score 0):

I also shell script using ffmpeg to resize images without alphachannel. It worked for png format fine.

```sh
# Export ios app icons by ffmpeg scale command
# usage: sh export_ios_icons.sh {path_to_your_img}
# example: sh export_ios_icons.sh ./app_icon.png

# sizes of images
# you can get other size images by editing thisarray
size=(20 40 60 29 58 87 80 120 180 76 152 167 1024)
for i in "${size[@]}"
do
   : 
    ffmpeg -i $1 -vf scale=$i:$i output_$ix$i.png
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried exporting without `alpha` it did not work for me but I figured it out that why I was getting error. I create an AppIcon using Figma & Sketch, but I tried to make a 2D geometry shape to 3D viewable. So I assume that I can achieve it by using some shadows & the same geometry but with lower alpha-like %70. After that, I got the AppIcon and export it without Alpha ticking but the problem was the main source of the image includes a container with lower alpha-like I did. So I change it to another graphical shape without alpha and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows so in my case I [used paint.net](https://www.getpaint.net/download.html).

1. Open the icon in question and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
2. A `Save configuration` dialog will pop out.
3. Select 24-bit Depth

[image]

After this icons got accepted.

**P.S**
Another option colleague suggested was to simply open with `ms paint` and save it, since paint does not support transparency, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Firt of all I change the logo to unAlpha and replace the previous icons via $flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons but it still doesn't work.
I removed finally the unassigned AppIcons & remove from the Contents.json all over icons such as iPad &TV icons cause I specified only iPhone version then It's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simpelest way I fixed this was opening the PNG in MS Paint saving it as a jpg. Than saved it back to PNG. That did remove the alpha channel.

Answer (score -3):

changed the icon from **.png** format to **.jpg** and everything went well.