# ionic3 - Invalid App Store Icon. The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in 'YourApp.app' can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic3

My ionic3 project build IOS successed, but when I upload it to itunes connect error showing

[image]

then I try follow this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47264220/6059754), but showing this for me `find: convert: No such file or directory`

EDIT:

I installed `imagemagick` using `npm install imagemagick` not `brew install imagemagick`

then running `find ./resources/ -name "*.png" -exec convert "{}" -alpha off "{}" \;` showing `find: convert: No such file or directory`.

Comment: The error is quite obvious. You can double check whether your PNG contains alpha channel or not, using IrfanView, Photoshop, etc.

Comment: @Raptor Thank you very much, error solved.

Comment: This maybe the most direct way to fix. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46609824/5492956

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Error solved!! Because of my ionic3 project contains icon `alpha channel` problem. And thanks to @Raptor.

1. I tried to close icon `alpha channel` by **photoshop**.
2. Delete `./resources/ios/icon` all icons which in `IOS` folder.
3. Run `ionic cordova resources ios`.
4. Rebuild ios `ionic cordova build ios --prod`, error solved.

***If still got error or any problem, just comment here and I will try to help you.***

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this on XCode on your Assets catalog.
Like (from Apple)
[image]

At the bottom of that screen you will see the required field:

[image]

It should be a 1024x1024 image

Comment: I am using ionic3, please

Answer (score 3):

The find command syntax is not  correct, this way you get the message, this how you should use find command :

```
  find . -type f \( -iname \*.png \)  -exec convert "{}" -alpha off "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Photoshop, you can also try it in the free Paint.Net:

- Load the file and save it again but select 24 bits in the options.
- You will see in the preview that the image will be rendered against a white background.

Thanks Midora from https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/30381-removing-the-alpha-channel/