# React Native Error ITMS-90717: “Invalid App Store Icon”

Tags: ios, react-native

I made app with React Native and it is almost done.

So tried to publish my application to App Store with Xcode(Application Loader) But it throws error like this.

[image]

Maybe this issue is duplicated with [Error ITMS-90717: "Invalid App Store Icon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585809/error-itms-90717-invalid-app-store-icon),

But It is little bit different with my case Because I made app with React Native. (I used EXPO XDE)

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a icon image without a transparent background. You can just export as JPG or export again the png whithout the transparent background / alpha

Comment: You mean that remove icon's alpha in assets/icon.png?