# Invalid App Store Icon

Tags: ios, xcode, virtual-machine, macos-sierra, appstore-approval

Can anyone help me here guys? I'm stuck with this issue. Tried it for about 15 times and still getting this error even though I followed all the possible fixes about Invalid App Store Icons.

[image]

Followed the requirements for the App Store Icon image.

I'm using a virtual machine MacOS Sierra 10.12 with a xcode version 8.3.3

Comment: It seems that at least of all the images you had to provide in your xcassets has transparency which is not allowed. Could you share the images you used in your asset catalog?

Comment: We would need to see the image/images so we detect which one has transparency

Comment: FYI:- From July you need to submit app from Xcode 9 or latter.

Comment: Here's my app icon guys. [App Icon](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zraDGj_sD9lVtugNXBDlmjFK9n9nsIWx)

Comment: Provide your icon to check.

Comment: :thinking-face: I'll keep that in mind @Anuraj Thanks for the info. :D

Comment: @vivekDas [App Icon](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zraDGj_sD9lVtugNXBDlmjFK9n9nsIWx)

Comment: Not able to access your icon . you need to make it public.

Comment: Oh my bad. Put it on public now @vivekDas [App Icon](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zraDGj_sD9lVtugNXBDlmjFK9n9nsIWx/view)

Comment: @DexterNunag upload with .jpg icon in 1024x1024 resolution and it works

Answer (score 11):

Its due to the following issues.

1. Check your icon should not contain and transparent background.
2. And it should not contain any alpha channel. To check alpha channel
   open the image in preview. and do file - > Export Then one screen
   will come, check the format and Alpha option should uncheck. Check
   the below images for reference.

[image]

[image]

After making the changes just save it.

Comment: It seems that I don't have that option [Screen shot for the export option](http://prntscr.com/kcprqn)

Any idea why I'm not having that option when exporting?

Comment: Okay, if option is not there means its alpha is fine, so now the problem is your png may contain transparent background, you need to remove it.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681869/images-cant-contain-alpha-channels-or-transparencies

Comment: Still having the same issue @vivekDas I think it's my xcode version :/

Comment: try recreate the app icon without alpha channel and transparent background and corners.

Answer (score 3):

What I did was I went through my Terminal to my folder where all the assets are, which is in Runner folder, and ran these commands:

```
brew install imagemagic
```

```
find ./resources/ -name "*.png" -exec convert "{}" -alpha off "{}" \;
```

Afterward I just archived the workspace again and then I validated it and it worked for me. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Upload with .jpg icon in 1024x1024 resolution and it works.

(you can export as jpg format and save it. after assign that jpg image to your app icon in your project assets.)

Answer (score 0):

Upload icon 1024 * 1024 size and ask your designer specifically to not use any transparent shade. All colours and shades must be of solid colour. Simple. Thanks